# Non-Steady Diffusion-Advection equation with time dependent Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: python, fipy

I would like to set up fipy to solve the 1D diffusion-advection equation with sinousoidal boundary.

I ended up with the following code:

```py
from fipy import *
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def boundary(t):
    return 1 + 0.1 * np.sin(6*np.pi*t)

nx = 50
dx = 1./nx
mesh = Grid1D(nx=nx, dx=dx)
n_model = CellVariable(name="density",mesh=mesh,value=1., hasOld=True)
D_model = CellVariable(name="D",mesh=mesh,value=mesh.x[::-1]*5.+3)
v_model = FaceVariable(name="v",mesh=mesh,value=1. )
v_model = (-1*mesh.x) * [[1.]]
n_model.constrain(boundary(0.), mesh.facesRight)
equation = (TransientTerm(var=n_model) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D_model,var=n_model) \
                + ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=v_model,var=n_model))
timeStepDuration = 0.9 * dx**2 / (2 * 1)  * 1e2
time_length = 2
steps = np.int(time_length/timeStepDuration)
t = 0
n_out = np.zeros((steps,nx))
import time
t1 = time.time()
for step in xrange(steps):
    t += timeStepDuration
    n_model.updateOld()
    n_out[step] = n_model.globalValue
    n_model.constrain(boundary(t), mesh.facesRight)
    equation.solve(dt=timeStepDuration)
print "Execution time: %.3f"%(time.time()-t1)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(n_out.T)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

The code runs fine and I get reasonable results. However it is also pretty slow, roughly 3.5 s for the cycle. Is there a better way to implement this? Or how can I speed up the system?

Comment: 3.5s is not that much. Is your actual problem that you want a finer mesh grid, or 2D/3D simulations, or something else that would require optimizing?

Comment: Well, I need to run this piece of code in a optimization routine and it takes foreever

Comment: That smells of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please give us the full problem ("running subroutine X in script Y takes forever" -> provide Y as well) instead of what you believe to be the adequate solution ("subroutine X is too slow").

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. Do you know if there is a better way to use fipy in a more time dependent way?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to keep re-constraining `n_model`. The constraints don't get replaced; they all get applied in succession. Instead, do what we demonstrate in [`examples.diffusion.mesh1D`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.mesh1D.html). Declare `t` as a `Variable`, constrain `n_model` in terms of this `Variable` and update the value of `t` at each time step. This goes about 4x faster for me.

```
from fipy import *
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def boundary(t):
    return 1 + 0.1 * np.sin(6*np.pi*t)

nx = 50
dx = 1./nx
mesh = Grid1D(nx=nx, dx=dx)
n_model = CellVariable(name="density",mesh=mesh,value=1., hasOld=True)
D_model = CellVariable(name="D",mesh=mesh,value=mesh.x[::-1]*5.+3)
v_model = FaceVariable(name="v",mesh=mesh,value=1. )
v_model = (-1*mesh.x) * [[1.]]
t = Variable(value=0.)
n_model.constrain(boundary(t), mesh.facesRight)
equation = (TransientTerm(var=n_model) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D_model,var=n_model) \
                + ExponentialConvectionTerm(coeff=v_model,var=n_model))
timeStepDuration = 0.9 * dx**2 / (2 * 1)  * 1e2
time_length = 2
steps = np.int(time_length/timeStepDuration)
n_out = np.zeros((steps,nx))
import time
t1 = time.time()
for step in xrange(steps):
    t.setValue(t() + timeStepDuration)
    n_model.updateOld()
    n_out[step] = n_model.globalValue
    equation.solve(dt=timeStepDuration)
print "Execution time: %.3f"%(time.time()-t1)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(n_out.T)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What if the user wants to change the type of the boundary to flux  at some time steps, e.g. when t>1?

Comment: @IgorMarkelov: You could [release](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.variables.html#fipy.variables.variable.Variable.release) the initial constraints and apply new ones